# Is there any way to recover a stored procedure overwritten with an ALTER statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have altered my stored procedure by mistake and I have no backup of the database. Is there any way of recovering my work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running this. It gets a list of the queries that are in the plan cache, it may be buried in there.

```
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The stored procedures are part of the database.

Take this as an opportunity to learn to do backups.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have sql server studio open with the tab used to generate the changes to your sp, not likely, but you can see if the old version is in your undo buffer.

A nice version control system and local sql history toolset would allow you to go back to virtually any point.